# Lib for creating ROC-Curve and DET-Curve by giving it the match scores and non-match-scores?

Tags: python, face-recognition, face-detection, roc, biometrics

Im comparing some Open-Source Face-Recognition-Frameworks running with python (dlib) and for that i wanted to create ROC and DET curves. For creating match-scores im using the casia faceV5 dataset. Everything is only for educational purpose.

My Questions is:

Whats the best way to generate these kind of curves? (Any good libs for that?)
I found this via google [Skicit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve) but i still dont know how i should use that for face recognition?
I mean, which information should i have to pass? I know that ROC is using the true match rate and the false match rate, but from a developers point of view i just dont know how to integrate these informations to that Skicit-function.

My Test:
Im creating genuine match-scores of every person in the casia dataset. Therefor i use different pictures of the same person to create it. I save this scores in the array "genuineScores".
Example:
Person**1**_Picture**1**.jpg comparing with Person**1**_Picture**2**.jpg
Person**2**_Picture**1**.jpg comparing with Person**2**_Picture**2**.jpg etc.

Im also creating impostor match-scores. For this im using two pictures of different persons. I save this scores in the array "impostorScores".
Example:
Person**1**_Picture**1**.jpg comparing with Person**2**_Picture**1**.jpg
Person**2**_Picture**1**.jpg comparing with Person**3**_Picture**1**.jpg etc.

Now im just looking for a lib where i could pass the two arrays and its creating a roc curve for me.
Or is there another method for doing so?

I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off topic. Simply ask for how to do it. If there is a good library, people will recommend it, but the knowledge is actually the knowing how.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyeer/